# How do you center an element w.r.t an already centered element in flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[![Red: Centered on canvas: Black: Centered between center and top of canvas][1]][1]

Using `flex`, it is easy to position elements in the center of a div. But how can this be done relative to already centered elements, using flex?

Shown below in the code is the best I've come up so far. I am able to center the red square in the middle but cannot get the blue one above it to be vertically center-aligned between the red square and the top border.

```css
.flex {
  border-style: solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100vh
}

.square {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

#square1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#square2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.flexdivider {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}

p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="flexdivider">
      <div class="square" id="square1"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="flexdivider">
       <div class="square" id="square2"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="flexdivider">
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lUop.png

Comment: Please post the code that you attempted till now

Comment: Just posted it. I am trying to figure out how to center the blue square between the red one and the wrapping div border.

Answer (score 0):

I have created 2 separated approach.

```css
h2{
  color: #333;
}
.box,.fakebox{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}

/* Example #1 */
.container-box-1{
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}
.fakebox{
  opacity: 0;
}
.box2{
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
}
```

```html
<h2>Example #1 (Using Display Flex and position absolute)</h2>
<div class="container-box-1">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box box2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Would you be able to modify your answer to show two boxes as depicted in my question? I understand what you're doing for just showing one box centered in the top-half of the screen. But I want to be able to get one box centered in the top-half of the screen AND one centered in the center of the screen. I'm not sure if your approach would still apply for that case?

Comment: Please check now, I have edit my answer.